# Understand the basic concept of a Makefile

Tags: linux, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I have the following makefile which I am trying to upgrade, but there is a certain element which I am not able to understand what means:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.f Makefile
       @$(F90) $(FFLAGS) $(POPTIONS) -o $@ $<    
%.o:        %.f Makefile
       @make $(OBJDIR)/$@
```

I understand that `$(OBJDIR)/%.o:` is obtained by executing the f90 compiler with flags etc. 
But why do I need the `%.o` rule, and what does `@make` mean. Am I missing a general understanding of how a Makefile work?

Comment: In isolation, this fragment doesn't make much sense. The two rules overlap, but the first one will take precedence for any file in `$(OBJDIR)/`. The second basically just redirects to the first. `make` simply runs `make` itself a second time, and the `@` prefix on both recipes should probably be removed at least while debugging so you can see what you are doing.

Comment: I expect the `%.o` rule is not used at all during any "normal" makefile processing.  I believe this rule was added to allow users to run commands like `make foo.o` to build just a single `.o` file.  Without this rule existing, to build a single `.o` file you'd have to run `make myobjdir/foo.o` (assuming the variable `OBJDIR` is set to the value `myobjdir`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@make` means invoke `make` but do not echo that in the output (`@` symbol). The correct way is `@${MAKE}` because `make` may not refer to the make being executed, whereas `${MAKE}` does.

In makefiles rules must create the target file they promise to (unless the targed is marked as `.PHONY`). Here, that `%.o` rule promises to build that `%.o`, but what it does in fact is it builds `$(OBJDIR)/%.o`. This is a broken rule.

Comment: Actually its `$(MAKE)` and not `${MAKE}`. See [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable).

Comment: @jml https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Reference - first sentence. My personal style is `${}` for variables and `$()` is for functions.